# Images from computer not showing up on Github io/pages

Tags: html, css

I've created a simple page using Visual Studio Code (HTML & CSS only at the moment) which I've managed to make look decent on my browser (thanks to the help with a few queries on here btw).

However, as I've pushed up to Giuthub I"m missing my logo (placed twice on the page). I've checked the syntax, case lettering etc and I've had a look on these threads for an answer, but I'm struggling to find a fix.

This is how it is written (in this case, in the navbar section) - stored on my mac:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="/Users/**********/documents/Norfbeech Creates/tasq_logo_5.png" width="190" height="70" alt="" />
    </a>
</nav>
```

I've also added the logo image at the bottom of the page and that too is not present.

Do you think the space in the folder where the image is held is affecting in via the white space? The actual image file has no spaces but would GitHub pick up on that space?

Would it be a good idea to create an image file in the project folder (Documents - HTML, CSS, Images)? I'm sending this over for review today and the images are quite essential to the look of the page.

I did briefly read something about encoding images but it was quite late when I logged off last night.

Many thanks.

Comment: path issue please correct the path by putting image in the main folder of your html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are referencing the wrong path.

Right now you have inserted the absolute position of the image, as it is saved on your hard drive.This will not work when you push your code on an external server.

You need to put the relative path of the image:
Imagine you have the following structure:

```
 - src
  - img/tasq_logo_5.png
  - index.html
```

In your index.html you want to reference the image as follows:

```
<img src="./img/tasq_logo_5.png" />
```

Comment: Ahh - so create a new 'images' folder, drop in the png and direct it (in my case) to : ```<img src="./imgages/tasq_logo_5.png" /> ``` I guess I'm not fully up on the relative/absolutw file paths so I'll brush up on that.  When I look at the file reference above I'm left wondering how the image is picked up just via ./images rather than the fuller route as before (/users/*****/documents/Norfbeech... etc. I've just tried the new relative path in VS Code and it works so I'll push it up to Giuthub and see if it works there.  Thanks very much!!

Comment: The absolute path is the position on your hard drive "/users/.../Norfreeb/../etc". When you upload the image on a server it is positioned on a different place in its hard drive, therefore it is no longer valid. When you reference it relatively, like "./images/logo.png", you are saying: from whatever folder I currently am in (./), look for the images folder and than look for logo.png

Comment: Intially didn't work in github but then that takes a while to 'refresh'...few moments later and all is working perfectly. Easier than I thought, but I've learned something new here! Thanks very much Aaron.